# How to authorize my Android application in IS4

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I have IdentityServer 4 deployed.
I also have an android application that I need authorized on that IS4 server.

Because this android app is NOT a phone (it is smart glasses) and cannot sign in using classic username/password method, how can I get access_token and Id_token for it?

My thought is this:

1. User wearing the glasses, scan the QR code he generated on a web-client where the user is logged in.
2. The app parses the data in the QR code and get WHAT? (best would be "authorization_code" but how to get one on the client, I only have exposed Id_token and acess_token)
3. The app requests access_token on a token endpoint.

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a look at the [Device Flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8628), which is designed for cases where a device doesn't have a browser. This involves the user logging on via a separate device while the limited device polls the Authorization Server.

This [Curity Article + Video](https://curity.io/resources/tutorials/howtos/flows/device-flow/) provides a pretty good overview. Identity Server will have support for this also. I don't claims to known much about Android Smart Glasses though :)

Comment: That's it! This is exactly what I need.